# .NET hidden field value not found after JQuery sets it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having a bit of a hard time trying to get a confirm box working with asp.  My issue right now, is that in my confirm javascript method I am updating a hidden field's value to either 1 or 0, and in the ASP function, I am checking whether or not the value is 1 or 0.  Currently the hiddenfield value is "".

Front End Code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="txtconfirmmessageValue" runat="server" />
/* redacted code*/
<asp:LinkButton ID="EndSessionLinkButton" CssClass="SessionDashboardButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmAll();" OnClick="EndSession" Text="CANCEL" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function confirmAll() {
        if (confirm("You are about to end session. Are you sure you want to do this.")) {
            $('#<%=txtconfirmmessageValue.ClientID %>').val(1);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=txtconfirmmessageValue.ClientID %>').val(0);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Behind Code ASP.NET

```
protected void EndSession(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = txtconfirmmessageValue.Value;
    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        value = txtconfirmmessageValue.Value;
    }

    if (!Utility.ToBool(txtconfirmmessageValue.Value))
    {
        return;
    }
    /* redacted */
}
```

The value of txtconfirmmessageValue is always "" and is never set, even tho I added alerts to the javascript method that alerted the value of the asp:hiddenfield after the event triggered.

NOTE:: I also added the while loop in there to by pass the post back of asp happening before the confirm box event was finished.. I am not sure how to postpone the postback until the confirm box is completed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your javascript?  Is it in the HTML that is rendered on the browser, or is it in an external file?  Also, you're not returning anything from `confirmAll` but using `return confirmAll();` in the click handler (Oh, and ASP != ASP.NET)

Comment: I tried your code and it works...i think the problem is somewhere else. Maybe there is another control generating the PostBack?

Comment: @freefaller ya I have the return true and return false respectively in my code I just forgot to add when I typed this up.

Comment: @freefaller also edited title and text for .NET instead. Thank you

Comment: If you are using webforms with viewstate... you should change the hidden field with a update panel and scripmanager (in order to save the state each time you change it). You can change the value with jquery but the viewstate will remain the same value than before.

Comment: Errr....you can't postpone the postback by using a server side method. By the time it gets to the server, it's already done the postback.

Comment: The page is probably submitting too early before the value is set. You'll need to trigger the postback from JavaScript after you set the value to make sure `__doPostBack()` isn't firing until you want it to. You should probably just use a regular html control in that case.

Comment: or you can just submit the form from JavaScript instead of calling `__doPostback()`

Comment: I cannot change the way the page works in that regards.  I was tasked with adding a confirmation before the end session function runs.

Comment: Well, you have to, in order for it to work correctly. You have to figure out a way to keep the form from submitting until after the confirm, which can only be done on the client, not server.

Comment: If you want the server side method to run still, you're going to have to use [GetPostBackEventReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do a postback on behalf of the button

Comment: @moarboilerplate this worked. so if you want to type up an answer with __doPostback() and the GetPostBackEventReferences i will close this one out!

Comment: The code above worked for me, as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since other page events fire when you click on a button, like `Page_Load`, make sure those events aren't firing and overwriting the value for your control.</strike>

The page is being posted back before jQuery is setting the value, so you need to prevent the postback from occurring until the user responds to the confirm.

In order to maintain the same behavior on your page, making sure the server-side method is still getting called, you'll want to do a postback on behalf of the button by using [GetPostBackEventReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing that I checked.  The only place I am setting value to the hidden field is in the JS method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the hidden field value from javascript, you can get it through `Request.Form[]` in codebehind.

`Request.Form[txtconfirmmessageValue.UniqueId]`

codebehind:

```
protected void EndSession(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = Request.Form[txtconfirmmessageValue.UniqueId];

    if (!Utility.ToBool(value))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: still receiving value = "", for both the request.form and also the textconfirmmessageValue.Value.

Answer (score 0):

If I put the parameter as a string instead of a int it works

```
 function confirmAll() {
        if (confirm("You are about to end session. Are you sure you want to do this.")) {
            $('#<%=txtconfirmmessageValue.ClientID %>').val("1");
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=txtconfirmmessageValue.ClientID %>').val("0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it fails if you leave them as numeric values?  My testing suggests it makes no difference

Comment: the "1" or 1 did not make a difference.. my hiddenfield value is still ""

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try my method fellowing

**Implements  IPostBackEventHandler**

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm",
  "if(confirm('check my tickets！'))" + this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this,  "true") + "; else " +
  this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "false"), true);

  public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
string res;
switch (eventArgument)
{
case "true":
res = "check！";  
break;
case "false":
res = "uncheck。";   
break;
default:
throw new NotSupportedException();
}
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + res + "');", true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use document.getElementById instead of Jquery selector. it will work.

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtconfirmmessageValue.ClientID %>").value=1;
```